# Delete page in Word

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I need VBA code to delete all sections(pages) except first in Word document

For this I use below code.

```
For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
    If oSec.Index <> 1 Then
        oSec.Range.Delete
    End If   
Next oSec
```

This works but does not delete second section only removes its content.
If I removes if condition in code it removes content of first page.

I want to preserve content of first page.

Please tell me where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deleting you need to include **section break marks**. Try to change this line:

```
oSec.Range.Delete
```

into this one:

```
ActiveDocument.Range(oSec.Range.Start - 1, oSec.Range.End).Delete
```

**BTW,** you should not think that page=section, they are different type of document units.

Comment: Hello KazJow, Thanks for your replay. Your code worked for me. I have worked in Excel-VBA but new in Word. So I dont know basic. How to understand difference between page and section. I didnt found any object like page in Word macro...

Comment: Yes, exactly, pages exist but they are rather visual part of your document. If you want to check number of pages you can check it in this way: `ActiveDocument.Windows(1).Panes(1).Pages.Count`.